# Output of text summarization is truncated

Tags: text, huggingface-transformers, summarization

I'm working with hugging face transformers for text summarization. Independently of the model used I get the last sentence of the summary truncated. So far I've tried increasing max_length in the .generate() function as well as adding a stopping criteria when a dot (.) is generated and set early_stopping=False. Still the output summary looks truncated since the last sentence is incomplete.

This is my code so far:

```py
from transformers import StoppingCriteriaList

def my_stopping_criteria(output):
    if output!=None:
        if "." in output["generated_text"]:
            return True
        
stopping_criteria = StoppingCriteriaList([lambda self, output: my_stopping_criteria(output)])

inputs = tokenizer(texto, return_tensors="pt").input_ids
outputs = model.generate(inputs, max_length = 1000, stopping_criteria=stopping_criteria, num_beams = 3, no_repeat_ngram_size=2, early_stopping=False)
tokenizer.decode(outputs[0],skip_special_tokens=True)
```

Does anyone know how on earth it is possible to obtain a full summary from hugging face transformer models for text summarization?

Comment: What is the input `texto`? Which model did you use? And what's your transformers version?

Comment: The input texto is a paragraph from a legal text. Transformer version is 4.28. I'm using T5 models and Bert.